# Как сохранить картинку из pictureBox в папку Pitures?

Tags: c#

Я делаю программу на подобии Paint, и мне нужна функция сохранения изображения. Как сохранить картинку из pictureBox в папку Pitures?

Comment: [Искать пробовали самостоятельно](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+picturebox+save+image)?

Comment: Да, пробовал один способ, не работает.

Comment: Ну так расскажите, что пробовали, покажите код, поясните, что именно не работает

Comment: Пробую так:
pictureBox.Image.Save("путь", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
Подчёркивается класс ImageFormat и ошибка: The name 'ImageFormat' does not exist in the current context

Comment: А, всё, понял, забыл using System.Drawing.Imaging, спасибо за материал, кстати.

Comment: Пожалуйста. Хорошо, что все решилось.

Comment: В Блокноте пишите? Visual Studio сейчас настолько мощная штука, что ошибки не просто подсвечивает, но и предлагает варианты исправления. Достаточно мышкой навести или хоткеем воспользоваться.